# ScreenDevice.getIDstring() strange value

Tags: java, c++, windows, native, multiple-monitors

I am creating a Java application that will run on both Linux and Windows. The application will execute native code for multiple-monitor configurations. Because of this, I want to pass the monitor's ID from Java to the native code. This has lead me to Java's ScreenDevice.getIDstring().

Javadocs claim that this method is useful for debugging, but that it also uniquely identifies a monitor. For Linux devices, it returns a usable ID string that allows the native code to quickly retrieve the desired monitor object.

On Windows, however, the method simply returns `/display0` for the first display, and then counts upwards for every following display (regardless if a graphics card contains both monitors, or if the monitors are on separate graphics cards).

When it comes to Windows C++ code, I have tried using `EnumDisplayDevices` and looking at the respective DeviceIDs and DeviceStrings. These do not match the values of Java:

- First Monitor - Java = `/display0`, Windows = `\\.\DISPLAY1`
- Second Monitor - Java = `/display1`, Windows = `\\.\DISPLAY7`

I am really confused as to where this `/display#` ID value is coming from... Where can I acquire the same `/display#` value when running native Windows C++ code?

Note: It would technically be possible to cycle through all existing displays to try and match the X/Y/width/height between the OS native code and Java, but this would be a lot of work and not very efficient. I would see this as a possible solution, but it is not very ideal.